# How to install codeigniter in xampp?

Tags: xampp

I have installed xampp in ubuntu.
Need to copy CodeIgniter into xampp.

Please tell me the procedures.

Answer (score 0):

After installing xampp on ubuntu

1. download latest version of codeigniter from terminal

   `wget https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/archive/3.0.4.zip`
2. unzip the file that

   `unzip ~/3.0.4.zip`
3. go to home folder codeigniter file as CI
4. copy the CI which is in home dir to htdocs of xampp

   `sudo cp -a /home/system5/CI /opt/lampp/htdocs`
5. type

   `http://localhost/CI/`

and check codeigniter page is displaying or not

Comment: What does "go to home folder codeigniter file as CI" mean, are you trying to say that we need to rename the codeigniter folder as CI?